# When can we use Gauss Hermite integration technique

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate the following integral:$\\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{f\left(x\right)}\frac{dx}{x}$. Where, $f\left(x\right)$ is a function of $x$. Is it correct to evaluate the integral by generating Gauss Hermite points and weights correcponding to $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ and then approximate the integral as $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\frac{e^{f\left(x_i\right)}}{x_i}$, where, $w_i$ and $x_i$ are weights and points of Gauss Hermite. 
In fact, I used this method to calculate this integral, but the result is not same as the one I obtained using monte carlo. So, I am just wondering whether G-H method is applicable here?

Comment: Based on my experience, I wouldn't trust G-H to properly evaluate the integral. Generally its good for integration against polynomials, but not so good for integration against trancendental functions.